# WhatsApp messages order

Tags: whatsapp, unificationengine

We are working on our chatbot that is connected to UIB. Some of our messages have a bit of a complex structure, and we need to split them up in order to send them in proper order. Consider, we have a single message that has the following content structure: `<text><image><text>`. In order to send this message to a WhatsApp user, we need to split the content into three messages (`#1 <text>; #2 <image>; #3 <text>`). If we send these messages one-by-one, in WhatsApp client we might receive these messages as in the order `<text><text><image>`, because posting images takes longer than posting text messages. We have a workaround (adding delay between requests) but images could be big in size, so it takes very long to send them. We could constantly increase delay, but it's not a good way to do such things.

So, my question is the following:

Is it possible to make a request to check the message status, whether it has been delivered to WhatsApp servers or not? Actually, it doesn't matter, whether the message were delivered to the end user, because users might be offline. We just need to know if the messages have been delivered to the WhatApp server in the proper order.

Answer (score 0):

You'll get the read/delivery status in the webhook URL.

Please contact support@uib.ai for further clarifications.